# Endpoint not returning models with async behind it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, endpoint

I have a C# api endpoint which returns some models to the caller. This is the (simplified) code :

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("test")]
  public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Test()
  {
    List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee { Name = "John" };
        StoreEmployeeAsync(employee.Name);
        Employees.Add(employee);
    }

    return Request.Ok(Employees);
  }

  private async void StoreEmployeeAsync(string name)
  {
      await _storer.PutName(name);
  }

  public async Task PutName(string name)
  {
    await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, name).ContinueWith(response => HandlePutPostResult(response));
}
```

When I debug it on line "return Request.Ok(Employees);" the List Employees contains the models I would expect, but the client calling the endpoint doesn't receive the models.
If I remove line "StoreEmployeeAsync(employee.Name);" everything works fine.

What is the problem here ? ... and how to solve it ?

Comment: It should be `private async Task StoreEmployeeAsync(string name)` and the call should be awaited: `await StoreEmployeeAsync(employee.Name);`

Comment: Or probably just `private Task StoreEmployeeAsync(string name) { return _storer.PutName(name); }`

Comment: I also wouldn't use "ContinueWith".